# I need to md5 the filename of a directory of files

Tags: command-line, bash, filename, md5sum

I need to get the md5sum of the filename of a directory. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
mv *.html md5sum(*).html
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what kind of command I need to run to do this?

Comment: md5sum of the of the filenames without the extension (.html) in the directory, not the directory itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
for i in *.html
do
    echo mv "$i" "$(md5sum <<<"${i%.html}" | awk '{print $1".html"}')"
done
```

`${i%.html}` in bash is the contents of the variable `i` (the current filename), with `.html` removed from the end. `awk '{print $1".html"}'` prints the first field of the output, with `.html` appended to it. We need this since `md5sum` adds a `-` to the output, since it is reading in from standard input:

```
$ md5sum <<<foo
d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00  -
$ md5sum <<<foo | awk '{print $1}'
d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00
```

Example:

```
$ for i in *.html
do
 echo mv "$i" "$(md5sum <<<"${i%.html}" | awk '{print $1".html"}')"
done
mv default.html de2b14ae7499f90736fc4a92327553a5.html
mv page.html 2adf521149526dde524f030851c7f903.html
mv post.html 0c0d03edf4e145ffd75eafb6d73deaa7.html
```

Remove the `echo` to actually move the files once you have verified the command works fine.

If you want the effect of `echo -n`, you can use that instead:

```
for i in *.html
do
    echo mv "$i" "$(echo -n "${i%.html}" | md5sum | awk '{print $1".html"}')"
done
```

Comment: Ok almost exactly what I needed except that your solution renders a different md5 than I need.
echo addImageToItem | md5sum = your solution
echo -n addImageToItem | md5sum renders what I need, I just need to apply it to 100 files

Comment: Eh? A different md5 than what you need? What md5 do you need?

Comment: sorry I hit enter when I should not have

Comment: @phpmydev see update. That's not difficult to achieve.